# Adding inline style to Gutenberg core blocks in the editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

In the Gutenberg editor I am trying to add inline styling to all (including core) blocks in the editor. Using [editor.BlockEdit](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#editor-blockedit), it is possible to make changes to all the blocks in the editor. For example, if I want to wrap them all and to the wrapper add some inline style (in the case a red color), I can do:

```
const withColorControl = createHigherOrderComponent((BlockEdit) => {
  return (props) => {
    return (
      <div style={{color: 'red'}}>
        <BlockEdit {...props}/>
      </div>
    );
  };
}, 'withColorControl');

addFilter('editor.BlockEdit', 'example/with-color-control', withColorControl);
```

My problem is though that this creates an extra `div`, which I do not want. What I would like is for the actual block to receive the inline styles, like so:

```
<Fragment>
  <BlockEdit {...props} style={{color: 'red'}}/>
</Fragment>
```

This does not work, therefore my question: **How to add inline styles to Gutenberg blocks in the editor without wrapping the block?**

PS Saving inline styles or whatnot is not a problem, this merely has to do with the editor.

PS2 Also [editor.BlockListBlock](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#editor-blocklistblock) does not work. Although this can be used to add a class to the element, I cannot add inline styles.

Answer (score 5):

There happens to be a `wrapperProps` you can pass to the component. Not mentioned in the docs, but something I stumbled upon in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56192925/how-do-we-add-custom-data-attributes-to-gutenburgs-editor-blocklistblock). So what you can do to pass inline styles to blocks in the editor:

```
const withInlineStyle = createHigherOrderComponent(
  ( BlockListBlock ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
      return (
        <BlockListBlock
          { ...props }
          wrapperProps={{style: {color: 'red'} }}
        />
      );
    }
  },
  'withInlineStyle'
);

wp.hooks.addFilter(
  'editor.BlockListBlock',
  'my-plugin/with-inline-style',
  withInlineStyle
);
```

It this example, all blocks with have an inline style of `color: red`.